# Parsing input from user in any order or format

Tags: php

I am having some trouble trying to figure out how to parse information collected from user. The information I am collecting is:

- Age
- Sex
- Zip Code

Following are some examples of how I may receive this from users:

- 30 Male 90250
- 30/M/90250
- 30 M 90250
- M 30 90250
- 30-M-90250
- 90250,M,30

I started off with explode function but I was left with a huge list of if else statements to try to see how the user separated the information (was it space or comma or slash or hypen)

Any feedback is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you not enforce a format? Separate inputs? Anything?

Comment: unfortunately, that's not an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy enough. The ZIP code is always 5 digits, so a simple regex matching `/\d{5}/` will work just fine. The Age is a number from 1 to 3 digits, so `/\d{1,3}/` takes care of that. As for the gender, you could just look for an `f` for `female` and if there isn't one assume `male`.

With all that said, what's wrong with separate input fields?

Comment: Not accurate, the zip-code in US comes in one of two known formats: XXXXX or XXXXX-XXXX. And that's only in the US. In other countries it can contain characters, spaces, different length etc.

Comment: The second regex fails; if the input is 90210 16 M, the age will match 902.

Comment: @Hugo - Well, `/\d{1,3}/` of course assumes that you've identified the zip code from the input string, and have either removed it, or are operating on the portion of the input that has not been identified as the zip code.

Comment: @alfasin Op stated the zip-code comes in that format.  There's no way to match any zip-code worldwide, unless you assume that it's the remainder after trimming the ages and sex.

Comment: @nickb There's little point in manipulating the strings if you're using regex, it's better to do the regex properly in the first place.

Comment: @Huge you're right, and that's exactly why the task is doomed to fail. That is, unless you know for sure in which format you'll receive the input.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use a few regular expressions:

- One that looks for 5 numeric digits: `[^\d]\d{5}[^\d]`
- One that looks for 2 numeric digits: `[^\d]\d{2}[^\d]`
- One that looks for a single letter:  `[a-zA-Z]`

**[EDIT]**

I've edited the RegExes.  They now match every one of the presented alternatives, and don't require any alteration of the input string (which makes it a more efficient choice).  They can also be run in any order.

Comment: How are these regexes "done properly in the first place"? `\s` [only matches](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) matches HT, LF, FF, CR, and space, where the second, fifth, and sixth examples in the OP have none of these characters encapsulating the zip code or age.

Comment: @nickb so which solution do you recommend I use?